# Selecting only rows with certain number from data table

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

So... Probably my title is missleading but...

What my code currently does..

```
SELECT TOP 12
    *,
    r.user_name
FROM
    something p
INNER JOIN users r ON p.fk_user_id = r.user_id
ORDER BY
    something_id DESC
```

It pretty much only takes things from bottom and sorting it by id...
But what I need additionally is somehow add WHERE something_season = number and select only those things with fixed number, not everything.

Any suggestion? I guess that I can't even put WHERE in there.

Comment: Why do you guess that you can't put a `WHERE` clause in that query? Have you tried?

Comment: inner join ...
WHERE ...
order by ...

Comment: @TomH Yes, and been failing for hours ._ . I guess it is cause I've been using method of fail it til you make it, but not this very time ;o

Comment: Do what HashPsi said, add the where clause there.

Comment: @HashPsi Thanks, I've been putting it after FROM and tried also after ORDER BY.. Stupid me

Comment: Please include your attempts next time as it will make it easier for others to spot the issue more quickly. The more information that you provide, the easier and faster it is to help you.

Comment: @TomH Thanks for advice. I surely will, but guess I should say it from very beggining. Thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put where as following:

```
SELECT TOP 12 *,r.user_name
FROM something p
INNER JOIN users r ON p.fk_user_id = r.user_id
WHERE something_season = number
ORDER BY something_id DESC
```

Comment: Geez. Thanks, it worked. I've been putting it after FROM and tried also after ORDER BY...it explains why it didn't worked out for me ._ .

Comment: @sagi, first of all I didn't saw the comments and secondly, it also was missing a colon after the TOP 12

Comment: Actually the correct syntax is SELECT TOP <number> * . There is no comma.

Comment: No problem @sagi, you can post your answer and Harugawa will mark it as answer.

Comment: Actually it wasn't my answer on the comments.. just mentioned that it was already answered @ehh